# Harmon.ie crashes Outlook 2016

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-2016, harmon.ie

We have several computers running Windows 7, MS Office 2016 and the enterprise version of harmon.ie. 
Every 30-40 minutes Outlook 2016 crushes with error message "Outlook is not responding", most often when you are composing a new message and you press the Send button.

We tried re-installing MS Office 2016, harmon.ie, applying the latest Win 7 and MS Office 2016 updates but still Outlook crushes. If we disable the harmon.ie add-in - all is fine, Outlook works perfectly.

The MS Office build that we use is: 16.0.4390.1000 64-bit
Do you have any tips on why this is happening and how we can solve this issue?

P.S.
The error in the Win Application log is always the same with event id 1000:

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        Application Error
Date:          13-Jul-16 8:42:30 AM
Event ID:      1000
Task Category: (100)
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      RWT-PWR-L374.rwt.local
Description:
Faulting application name: OUTLOOK.EXE, version: 16.0.4393.1000, time stamp: 0x573b33e3
Faulting module name: ucrtbase.DLL, version: 10.0.10586.9, time stamp: 0x5642c48d
Exception code: 0x40000015
Fault offset: 0x000000000006990f
Faulting process id: 0x1a58
Faulting application start time: 0x01d1dcf63851e66f
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\system32\ucrtbase.DLL
Report Id: 42e91501-48f7-11e6-b0eb-5cc5d4caf3ae
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Application Error" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>100</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-07-13T12:42:30.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>11369</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>RWT-PWR-L374.rwt.local</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>OUTLOOK.EXE</Data>
    <Data>16.0.4393.1000</Data>
    <Data>573b33e3</Data>
    <Data>ucrtbase.DLL</Data>
    <Data>10.0.10586.9</Data>
    <Data>5642c48d</Data>
    <Data>40000015</Data>
    <Data>000000000006990f</Data>
    <Data>1a58</Data>
    <Data>01d1dcf63851e66f</Data>
    <Data>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE</Data>
    <Data>C:\WINDOWS\system32\ucrtbase.DLL</Data>
    <Data>42e91501-48f7-11e6-b0eb-5cc5d4caf3ae</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have checked the crash dumps. The crash --does not occur nor originate from harmon.ie-- but from Outlook probably when running a call back (not one of our call back,). harmon.ie hence only uncovers the issue with ESET on Outlook 2016, note harmon.ie is deployed over 1.5 million users and we have never been reported such crash. ESET/Outlook 2016 contributes to the problem. If removing ESET "read email" option or even the plugin itself I suggest you contact ESET support. None of the dumps indicate a crash in harmon.ie. Indeed, the stack traces of the crash clearly indicates it occurs from a thread using VCRUNTIME140 , harmon.ie does definitely not use it (it is a ,net plugin) nor Outlook. ESET probably does.

```
00000000`0015bdc0 000007fe`f861abdf KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x39
00000000`0015be90 000007fe`f815f718 clr!UMThunkStubRareDisableWorker+0x3f
00000000`0015bec0 00000000`774d8802 clr!UMThunkStub+0x128
00000000`0015bf50 00000000`774bf5e7 user32!DispatchHookA+0x164
00000000`0015bfb0 00000000`774c4869 user32!CallHookWithSEH+0x27
00000000`0015bfe0 00000000`775fba75 user32!_fnHkINLPMSG+0x8c
00000000`0015c030 00000000`774c90ca ntdll!KiUserCallbackDispatcherContinue
00000000`0015c0e8 00000000`774c9095 user32!ZwUserPeekMessage+0xa
00000000`0015c0f0 000007fe`fedc7372 user32!PeekMessageW+0x105
00000000`0015c140 000007fe`fedc5716 msctf!RemovePrivateMessage+0x83
00000000`0015c1b0 000007fe`fedc7e4c msctf!SYSTHREAD::DestroyMarshalWindow+0x3c
00000000`0015c1e0 000007fe`fedc7d3c msctf!TF_UninitThreadSystem+0xfd
00000000`0015c230 00000000`775d99e4 msctf!CicFlsCallback+0xa4
00000000`0015c270 00000000`775d2889 ntdll!RtlProcessFlsData+0x84
00000000`0015c2b0 00000000`775d27c0 ntdll!LdrShutdownProcess+0xa9
00000000`0015c3d0 000007fe`f2635f8f ntdll!RtlExitUserProcess+0x90
00000000`0015c400 000007fe`f2b7dff8 mscorwks!SafeExitProcess+0xc7
00000000`0015c680 000007fe`f2790e3c mscorwks!EEShutDownHelper+0x678
00000000`0015c6b0 000007fe`f8ad9170 mscorwks!CorExitProcess+0x13c
00000000`0015c790 000007fe`f8bb7e2d mscoreei!RuntimeDesc::ShutdownAllActiveRuntimes+0x1f4
00000000`0015ca80 000007fe`eee2bc9d mscoree!ShellShim_CorExitProcess+0x10e
00000000`0015cab0 000007fe`eee2bbde ucrtbase!swprintf+0x2a9
00000000`0015cae0 000007fe`eee2bb3e ucrtbase!swprintf+0x1ea
00000000`0015cb10 000007fe`eee29919 ucrtbase!swprintf+0x14a
00000000`0015cb70 000007fe`d30561b7 ucrtbase!abort+0x69
00000000`0015cba0 000007fe`eee2902f OLMAPI32!Validate_SetValidationFlags+0x89b7
00000000`0015cbd0 000007fe`eeed39ba ucrtbase!terminate+0x1f
00000000`0015cc00 000007fe`eeedc710 VCRUNTIME140!__std_terminate+0xa
00000000`0015cc30 000007fe`eeed282a VCRUNTIME140!_CallSettingFrame+0x20
00000000`0015cc60 000007fe`eeed1b82 VCRUNTIME140!__FrameUnwindToState+0x136
(Inline Function) --------`-------- VCRUNTIME140!__FrameUnwindToEmptyState+0x7e
00000000`0015ccd0 000007fe`eeedbe80 VCRUNTIME140!__InternalCxxFrameHandler+0x19a
00000000`0015cd30 00000000`775d7f0d VCRUNTIME140!__CxxFrameHandler+0x90
00000000`0015cd80 00000000`775c7d4c ntdll!RtlpExecuteHandlerForUnwind+0xd
00000000`0015cdb0 00000000`773c054e ntdll!RtlUnwindEx+0x539
00000000`0015d450 000007fe`f8093095 kernel32!RtlUnwindExStub+0x1e
00000000`0015d490 000007fe`f80910a4 MSVCR120_CLR0400!UnwindNestedFrames+0x109
00000000`0015da50 000007fe`f8091793 MSVCR120_CLR0400!_DestructExceptionObject+0x134
00000000`0015dad0 000007fe`f8091528 MSVCR120_CLR0400!_DestructExceptionObject+0x823
00000000`0015db80 000007fe`f8092857 MSVCR120_CLR0400!_DestructExceptionObject+0x5b8
00000000`0015dc70 000007fe`f8093127 MSVCR120_CLR0400!_InternalCxxFrameHandler+0x213
00000000`0015dce0 00000000`775d7e8d MSVCR120_CLR0400!_CxxFrameHandler+0x77
00000000`0015dd30 00000000`775c84cf ntdll!RtlpExecuteHandlerForException+0xd
00000000`0015dd60 00000000`775fbac8 ntdll!RtlDispatchException+0x45a
00000000`0015e440 00000000`00000000 ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatch+0x2e
```

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely not a well-known issue.
Bear in mind the crash occurs in Windows C runtime in ucrtbase.dll dll, not inside harmon.ie.
It could be that harmon.ie simply uncovers a problem.

-Please download check latest harmon.ie version 5.4 from our web site.
Disable all the addins except harmon.ie:
In order to rule out any plugin conflict would you please check whether any additional plugins are enabled in Outlook - if so, disable (temporarily) all other add-ins except harmon.ie To disable Outlook add-ins
•   Go under File -> Options -> Add-ins -> Manage COM Add-ins and click Go...
•   Deselect all add-ins except harmon.ie and click OK.

Restart Outlook - and go back under File -> Options -> Add-ins to verify that harmon.ie is the only add-in listed in the Active application add-ins section.

If you still reproduce with our latest 5.4 version and after disbaling all the other addins as detailed previously:
Get a couple of crash dumps by running the below command in a cmd window after starting Outlook.
procdump.exe -64 -ma outlook -e  harmonie.dmp

Procdump utility can be downloaded at: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx

Upload the dumps at:
ftpus.mainsoft.com
User: free
Password: free

Let me know when the dumps get uploaded.

Thanks,

---- Jean

Comment: Thanks Jean, I downloaded the latest version and it's already deployed to 2 users. Now we are testing Outlook behavior with only harmon.ie add-in enabled. I will let you know about the details of our tests once we are sure the issue is resolved or not. Thank you!

Comment: Hi Jean, after a lot of testing it seems that I found the reason for the Outlook 2016 crashing. It is a combination of two add-ins: ESET Outlook add-in and harmon.ie.
If in the ESET add-in -> Email client protection the “Read Email” setting is enabled Outlook 2016 crashes unexpectedly. If I disable this  setting, everything is working great.
Four dump files are uploaded to your ftp and a print screen from ESET add-in with disabled Read email setting.
P.S. I've tried downgrading my MS Office to 2013 and everything is working fine with both ESET and harmon.ie add-ins enabled.

Comment: Hi, I have checked the crash dumps. The crash --does not occur nor originate from harmon.ie-- but from Outlook probably when running a call back (not one of our call back,). harmon.ie hence only uncovers the issue with ESET on Outlook 2016, note harmon.ie is deployed over 1.5 million users and we have never been reported such crash. ESET/Outlook 2016 contributes to the problem. If removing ESET "read email" option or even the plugin itself I suggest you contact ESET support. None of the dumps indicate a crash in harmon.ie.